# Nominalized adjective and inflection form to pronoun irgendwer and irgendwas

Tags: pronoun

Does the pronoun **irgendwer** precedes Nominalized adjective like pronoun **irgendwas** (Süßes) and which is the adjective inflection form after these pronouns?

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule for adjective endings is they are weak if the determiner already has a strong ending. For **irgendwer**, that means the adjectives get mixed inflection.

> Irgendwer Junges komme doch mal bitte her. *(Nom)*
>
> Sie gedenken irgendwem Unbekannten. *(Gen)*
>
> Gib es irgendwem Netten. *(Dat)*
>
> Wir sehen irgendwen Alten. *(Akk)*

Please note the irregular **-m** ending on the pronoun in the genitive case. By the book, it should be *irgendwessen*, but really no one uses that form.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91681/discussion-on-answer-by-janka-nominalized-adjective-and-inflection-form-to-prono).